# Proving divergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am attempting to establish divergence of the following series at $x=1/e$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}$$
Most of my ideas have revolved around the comparison test, but I haven't been able to find a divergent series which is less than my original series. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Set $x=e^{-1}$ and $a_n=x^{1+\ldots+1/n}$. Prove that $|\ln{(n+1)a_{n+1}}-\ln{na_n}|$ has a finite sum, thus $a_n \sim c/n$ for some $c >0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render

$(1/1)+(1/2)+(1/3)+...+(1/n)<1+\int_1^n(1/t)dt=1+\ln(n)$

due to $f(t)=1/t$ being monotonically decreasing for positive $t$.  Then

$(1/e)^{(1/1)+(1/2)+(1/3)+...+(1/n)}>(1/e)^{1+\ln(n)}=(1/(en))$

and your series compares with the harmonic series.

Comment: Typo in the final identity.

Comment: @Oscar The use of that precise integral to arrive at the inequality is quite an elegant solution. I wish I could come up with such ideas. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A secondary exercise:  Use the integration of the reciprocal function to render $(sum)>\ln(n)$, noting the reversed inequality sign.  Show that if we then make the base any positive number _less than_ $1/e$, the series becomes convergent.

Comment: @Oscar, If $x<\frac{1}{e}$, then $x^{sum}<\frac{1}{ne^{1/n}}$ (using above mentioned inequality). Now using Ratio Test on $\sum\frac{1}{ne^{1/n}}$, we can show that it converges, which implies that $\sum x^{sum}$ also converges. Am I correct?

Comment: You should get a comparison term (proportional to) $n^{\ln(x)}$ where $x$ is the base.  A big hint:  exponentiation has a quasi- commutative law, $a^{\ln(b)}=b^{\ln(a)}$.